# Other words for "jumping in excitement"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have this young character and I'm trying to describe his excitement through his body language. Is there any other words or expression which means *"jumping up and down with excitement"* or something with a similar meaning?
For example:

> The boy gently pulled his mother's hand "Come, mommy!" He jumped in
>   excitement, wanting to go as soon as possible

Thank you!

Comment: *Gently* doesn't sound consistent with the excitement. Consider: "The boy *sprang up* from his chair, *excitedly* pulling his mother's hand ...".

Comment: @Lawrence Nice catch there. I completely missed that. In my story, the boy was not sitting down. "He ran through the grassland and reached his mother." Instead of _ran through_, what other ways could we say he was running, but in an excited way?

Comment: Try saying he *skittered*, *danced* or *whooped* through the grassland.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider using “hopped about/around” in a suitable simile to try to capture the image you’re after:

> [He hopped about/around like a [an excited] baby
>   bunny](http://archiveofourown.org/works/610855/chapters/1100624)/chick/sparrow,
>   wanting to go as soon as possible.

(example usage from ‘Jeeves and the Christmas Grotto’ [Chapter 1, paragraph 5] via ‘archiveofourown[dot]org’)

Answer (score 4):

A few synonyms pop up if you google *excitement* - *exhilaration, elation, animation, enthusiasm, eagerness, anticipation, feverishness, fever, delirium, agitation, emotion, fire, fieriness, intensity, zeal, zest;* informal *pep, vim, zing, spark*

You could also replace *jumping* with *bouncing* which seems better to convey the idea of excitement.

***He was bouncing up and down with enthusiasm***. How about that?

Answer (score 1):

What WS2 said. I would like to add this:

**Jump for joy**, from [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jump+for+joy)

> to be very happy about something good that has happened
>
> *"Tina jumped for joy when she found out she'd be in the team."*

**Leap at the opportunity**, from [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leap+at+the+opportunity) (leap/jump at the chance/opportunity)

> *Fig.* to accept an opportunity eagerly.
>
> *"Frank leapt at the opportunity to become a commercial artist."*
> *"It was a great idea and we leapt at the opportunity."*
> *"I would leap at the chance to go to Moscow."*
> *"His company proposed to send him to England, and John jumped at the chance."*

Answer (score 0):

These are not the same as jumping but could describe body-language excitement:

[Shiver](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shiver) (of delight). The definition only speaks about fear and cold though.

> shiver (shĭv′ər)
>   v.intr.
>   1. To shake or tremble, as from cold or fear. See Synonyms at shake.
>   2. To quiver or vibrate, as by the force of the wind.

[Thrill](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thrill)

> thrill (thrĭl)
>   v.tr.
>   1. To cause to feel a sudden sensation of pleasure or delight; excite greatly: was thrilled to learn that she had won the contest.
>   2. To cause to quiver, tremble, or vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **Giddy**, from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giddy)

> feeling or showing great happiness and joy

Or from [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/giddy)

> 2. Frivolous and lighthearted; flighty: *was giddy with excitement at the news.*